# Laravel 5 form validation rules

Tags: validation, laravel-5

Is there a way where I can have a form validation rule in laravel 5, where the field must be min:6 or zero?

Regards, Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why a field should be a minimum of zero, but I guess you mean the field should be optional(not required). Here goes a Sample Request class you could use:

```
<?php namespace CRM\Http\Requests;

use CRM\Http\Requests\Request;


class PostRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */


    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        return [ 'title'=> 'sometimes|required|min:6' ];
    }

}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: sometimes was what I looked for:-)